# jQueryUI with multiple accordions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got 3 accordions in some tabs my content doesn't show properly pics and code below,

[image]

[image]

```
<div id="tabs">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1">BREAKFAST</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2">LUNCH</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-3">DINNER</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

                    </div>
```

same code above in both other tabs......

cheers,

Comment: Do you have `<div id="accordion">` on all three tabs? That could be a problem, as ids should be unique. If not, can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: no i added 1,2,3 to the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`heightStyle` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle) for the accordions. You can set it to `"content"` or `"fill"` depending on the desired behaviour, keeping in mind that initially the closed tabs are not visible and so they have no height. It might be a good idea to have a set height for the tabs, but that really depends on your page layout. The tabs widget also has a [`heightStyle` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-heightStyle) you might want to fiddle with.

Example:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();

$('.accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tej2A/)

Comment: ok thanks, i cant get it working right now i'll try in the morning and get back to you

Comment: morning! not showing the tabs now think its something to do with my js  http://jsfiddle.net/natharman/4A2tg/

Comment: That's totally different than what you originally asked about.. It has 3 tabs widgets instead of one. Also, your HTML for the tabs is wrong, each tabs should have a `<ul>` for the tab headers, followed by divs for the tabs themselves. Inside the divs, you put the accordion divs. Check my jsfiddle HTML.

Comment: hey, sorry i'm still a noob, i just tried it and its not doing anything now, i literally just copied your jsfiddle

Comment: The pic doesn't help.. and you didn't literally copy my jsfiddle. I told you what the problems with your fiddle are. Your question was about *one* tabs widget. Your fiddle has 3. If that's what you need, make a new separate question. My jsfiddle works like you asked for so I donno what you're trying to do

Comment: I edited your jsfiddle, added a tabs widget that surrounds the actual 3 tabs you had: http://jsfiddle.net/4A2tg/1/

Comment: working perfect now :) thanks allot u've really helped me out have a good weekend